# How to configure Jenkins to report major errors to the administrator?

Tags: jenkins, error-handling

e.g. I have the following errors in jenkins.err.log. How can I make Jenkins email this type of errors to me?

```
caused by: com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.exceptions.UnauthorizedException: Authorization failure connecting to 'http://vstsprodapp:8080/Services/v1.0/Registration.asmx' (authenticating as domain\user)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a feature that's built into Jenkins.

You could use whatever system you use for monitoring your servers, and check the logs on the Jenkins server for error messages.

There is also an idea suggested on the Jenkins wiki, which allows you to use a [Groovy hook script](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Hook+Script) to add a further Java logging handler to Jenkins.  But again, even if you do this, you would still have to implement a custom solution to send notifications based on the log's contents.

From [https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Logging](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Logging#Logging-MakinglogsavailableoutsideofthewebUI):

> Put the following Groovy script into a file called `$JENKINS_HOME/init.groovy.d/extra_logging.groovy`:
>
> ```
> import java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
> import java.util.logging.LogManager
>
> def logger = LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger("hudson.WebAppMain")
> logger.addHandler (new ConsoleHandler())
> ```
>
> This will just copy all log records generated by Jenkins and any plugins to the console.

Comment: I did that, and I see this in the system log:Executing C:\Tools\Jenkins\init.groovy.d\extra_logging.groovy. Where is this console?